# Is there a posibility to generate value-object wrappers for primary keys in JOOQ?

Tags: jooq, jooq-codegen

for example, there is a table:

```
table product (id UUID, name varchar)
```

Is it possible to generate for this table classes like code bellow?

```
class ProductIdentifier {
    UUID id;
}

class Product {
    ProductIdentifier id;
    String name;
}
```

I'm just asking. I didn't try

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the feature is called ["embedded keys"](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-embeddable-types/codegen-embedded-keys/), where the code generator automatically generates an [embeddable type](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-embeddable-types/) (single column or composite, it doesn't matter) for both:

- Primary keys
- All referencing foreign keys

Of course, you can also do this manually, yourself, by declaring embeddable types for each key.